# Anylogic - queue based on processing times DB

Tags: anylogic, job-scheduling

I am doing a job shop scheduling resorting to anylogic. I have 20 jobs (agent with a database of the machine sequence for each job) and 5 machines (resources).

[This is what I have right now. Source creates the 20 jobs and in the exit block i have the 'nextmachine' function, that sends each job to the correct machine of its sequence.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfJpy.png)

Now I want to use other DB table, the one with the processing times of each job in the machines of each job sequence. I want to order all queues in order to the shortest processing time. I created a new agent, 'processingTimes', using the new database table, and I am trying to associate the jobs id with the processingTimes ones so that the processing times are correctly associated.

[Processing times table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBpzd.png)

[I created this collection, inside my new agent, containing the processing times of each job.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge87F.png)

[Did this, trying to associate both agents id but I think it is not correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlc0Q.png)

[Finally, this is the condition I put so that I can order my jobs in relation to their processing times. I also think the code is not correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kwrA.png)

Any tips in what I am doing wrong?

New:

[This is my iterator but gives me the errors showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zp3j.png)

[New collection properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOog4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following changes are required:

1. remove **Choice condition** when loading *processingTimes* from database
2. create a collection of type LinkedHashMap of int->ProcessingTime, let's call it `col_jobProcTimes`
3. Main->On startup - iterate through `processingTimes[]` population and put them into the `col_jobProcTimes` map for later lookup
4. the two agents in Queue "agent1 is preferred to agent2" field are **Job**s, so for each job you need to do: `col_jobProcTimes.get((job)agent.jobpt).col_processSequence.get((job)agent.counter)` to get the double value for the delay and compare the two

---

Update.

Regarding pt. 3 above, the code should be:

```java
for (ProcessingTimes pt : processingTimes) {
    col_jobProcTimes.put(pt.jobpt, pt);
}
```

AnyLogic help website has a good reference for working with java [here](https://anylogic.help/advanced/index.html).

Comment: Ok I removed the choice condition and I assumed that collection 'col_jobProcTimes' is created in mais correct? If yes, that is what I have done. I updated the question with my iteration through the agent population code because I don't think I am doing it correctly. Thank you

Comment: i've modified the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I think I finished what I wanted to do, thanks to you!

Comment: Cool, can you please close the question?